# Is my code falls into any design pattern ?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have this piece of code:

```
private String objectToString(Object obj){
if (obj instanceof String)
    return (String)obj;
if (obj instanceof Struct){
    Map<String,?> map = ((Struct)obj).getMembers();
     return map.toString();
 }
Class c = obj.getClass();
if (c.isArray())
{
    //obj. iterate elements and return values;
    return obj.toString();//to redi this

}
//this is for any other datatypes
else
    return obj.toString();
```

}

Can someone suggest if this falls into any design patterns from GOF.Code is straightforward but just to clarify it looks at the parameter passed and depending on the type returning the string in a human readable form back.

Comment: I'd say this is an anti-pattern. I'd storngly suggest that for each object you just override the toString() method and completely scratch your current solution

Comment: @LordDoskias and Jack - care to explain 'why?'? [The point being: Until you explain 'why?', both your comments might just be 'personal opinion']

Comment: @LordDoskias while using `if instanceof else instanceof` is bad there is no alternative when you can't modify the classes used, which is especially the case with array types. Thought the check for String is unnecessary since toString() would act the same way.

Comment: agree with toString on String,

Answer (score 6):

Your code is is a clear example of an anti-pattern. The most clean way would be to simply override the toString() method of every object you want to have custom textual representation of. For example everytime you invoke System.out.println(someObject) - what java does it call the toString() of this particular object.

Here is an [article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55) explaining how/why it is a good idea to override. Just think about it - why do you have to center logic regarding textual representation of DIFFERENT objects which might not have absolutely nothing in common? That's the exact reason why the toString() is part of Java's Object object and since every class in java implicitly inherits from Object it makes perfect sense to override the toString() method.

Overriding a toString() method also gives you access to the internal state of an object which might be required if you want to make a proper textual representation, something which is not easily done with your proposed implementation (while it is certainly possible to have public fields, or getters etc. it makes no sense to do that just for the sake of textual representation).

Comment: Thank you for expanding your comment and explaining why this is an anti-pattern. +1.

Comment: I have no access to Struct class, it is third party library. And what about arrays?

Comment: Since struct is a third party class then you can't do anything, apart from wrapping it in your own object, and overriding the toString of YOUR object which in turn would invoke public methods from struct.

Comment: you do it manually for (Something blah : arr) { magic } - maybe a class with static methods for the array which hold the types you are interested in

Comment: Also I would still need to wrap the Struct on the fly at run time , so this will not be much different.

Comment: Array that is what I planned initially iterate the array and for each element print the content

Answer (score 0):

You are attemping to use an [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern where you should really be using polymorphism.

Implement proper toString() on your `Struct` and you are home. I.e.

```
public class Struct {
    ...
    public String toString() {
        return getMembers().toString();
    }
}
```

The rest of your code is redundant (`(String) obj` and `obj.toString()` will produce the same result if obj is a string).